# Why would a Date constructor with 0 long value as argument will output a date before 1970 in Java?

Tags: java, date, epoch

I know they consider the ***`epoch`*** to be the number of milliseconds since January 1st 1970 at midnight.

However, when I set:

```
System.out.println(new Date(0));
```

I get:

> `Wed Dec 31 18:00:00 CST 1969`

As it'd go backwards, why?

### Silly edit:

**Yes, I'm at GMT -6**

Comment: It hasn't gone backwards. What is your timezone?

Comment: I'm going to guess "somewhere in middle America"  ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The epoch starts at January 1st, 1970, at midnight UTC.  Your system default timezone is probably 6 hours off of UTC at that time.  (This is why functions that use system defaults without making that choice explicit are bad.)

Answer (score 0):

The `java.util.Date` object is not a real date-time object like the [modern date-time types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html); rather, it represents the number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely `January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT` (or UTC). When you print an object of `java.util.Date`, its `toString` method returns the date-time in the JVM's timezone, calculated from this milliseconds value.

Since your JVM's timezone offset is `-06:00` hours, `January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT` is being displayed as `Wed Dec 31 18:00:00 CST 1969`. If you need to print the date-time in GMT (or UTC), you will need to set the corresponding timezone to `SimpleDateFormat` and obtain the formatted string from it e.g.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date date = new Date(0);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX", Locale.ENGLISH);
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));
        System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z
```

With the release of Java SE 8 (March 2014), the outdated and error-prone legacy date-time API (`java.util` date-time types and their formatting type, `SimpleDateFormat` etc.) was supplanted by `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Using `java.time`, the modern API:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instant instant = Instant.EPOCH;
        System.out.println(instant);

        // Alternatively,
        instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(0);
        System.out.println(instant);

        // The same instant in your JVM's timezone
        ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Mexico_City"));
        System.out.println(zdt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1970-01-01T00:00:00Z
1970-01-01T00:00:00Z
1969-12-31T18:00-06:00[America/Mexico_City]
```

[`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) represents an instantaneous point on the timeline. The `Z` in the output is the [timezone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) for zero-timezone offset. It stands for Zulu and specifies the `Etc/UTC` timezone (which has the timezone offset of `+00:00` hours).

Learn more about `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>